# dyld[2932]: Library not loaded

Tags: ios, xcode, game-engine, dyld

I am currently Programming a Game Engine with C++ and Xcode. It has iOS and Mac support! The Engine compiles into a .dylib file. My Program linked with the Engine works just fine on my Mac. It also works in the iOS Simulator. But when i try to execute it on my Device it crashes. The Output:

`dyld[2932]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libGameGears.dylib Referenced from: <DD6C5269-FC7E-34C0-98E6-4E57F8A3C98E> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2EE68390-F98A-483B-B3DC-99680A1060A0/GameGears-iOS.app/GameGears-iOS Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/system/introspection/libGameGears.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/usr/local/lib/libGameGears.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/libGameGears.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/local/lib/libGameGears.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/libGameGears.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache)`

Thank you for your Help.

Things that have already tried:

- Setting the Library Search Path
- Setting the Runtime Path
- I checked Device compatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. Turns out iOS and it's Child Platforms don't support standalone Dynamic Libraries. You must wrap them into a Framework. [Solved by eskimo on the Apple Developer Forum]